# jQuery gMap, Need to set Language for lables

Tags: jquery, google-maps, jquery-gmap

I have created a map with [jQuery gMap](http://gmap.nurtext.de/)

I need the map to view Arabic language for labels (countries and cities), not the Default (English). Any idea how to do that?!!

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer and would like to share it.
in the Script tag that includes the Google Maps API, just Add the **hl** parameter andset it to any language you want (hl=ar).

The script should look like:

```
<script type="text/javascript" 
src="http://maps.google.com/maps?file=api&hl=ar&v=2&key=API_KEY"
></script>
```